# How to get equivalent of ResultSetMetaData without ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, metadata

I need to resolve a bunch of column names to column indexes (so as to use some of the nice `ResultSetMetaData` methods). However, the only way that I know how to get a `ResultSetMetaData` object is by calling `getMetaData()` on some `ResultSet`.

The problem I have with that is that grabbing a ResultSet takes up uneccesary resources in my mind - I don't really need to query the data in the table, I just want some information about the table.

Does anyone know of any way to get a `ResultSetMetaData` object without getting a `ResultSet` (from a potentially huge table) first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could use

```
DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
databaseMetaData.getColumns(null, null, tableName, "%");
```

It returns one row for each table column.

In this case you'd use the returned `ResultSet` itself, not its `ResultSetMetaData`.

One advantage of this approach is, that it doesn't interfere with database locking and transactions.

Comment: ^^^ This!!! However, with the caveat it puked out on my on Sybase running on HP. This was on 2001 mind you. But in general, this is the way to do it.

Comment: You're correct - looking into this method made it clear that it works in a cleaner manner.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're doing a `select * from mytable` you could just add a `where` clause that ensures no records will be returned and the ResultSet will be empty?

That way you are still just getting the metadata for the table you are interested in instead of the entire database.

Comment: Yep, this is what I figured out as well. I ended up using a LIMIT 1 clause instead of the WHERE clause for clarity, but it seems to be doable both ways.

Comment: This is however a bit hacky. Just using the `DatabaseMetaData` is more neat.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution

```sql
select * from mytable limit 0;
```

Then the query dont get any data.