# Obtaining metadata from MySQL in Java

Tags: java, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get equivalent of ResultSetMetaData without ResultSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564043/how-to-get-equivalent-of-resultsetmetadata-without-resultset)

```
StringBuffer queryBuffer=new StringBuffer("SELECT * FROM "+tableName);
PreparedStatement preparedStatement=getConnection("root", "").prepareStatement(queryBuffer.toString());
ResultSet resultSet=preparedStatement.executeQuery();
ResultSetMetaData resultMetaData=resultSet.getMetaData();
```

from the upper code I got `ResultSetMetaData` instance and from that I can get any information about table.

but I don't want to enter select query like above, and want to get information about table.

Comment: Looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564043/how-to-get-equivalent-of-resultsetmetadata-without-resultset.

See accepted answer in here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get the columns in a table you can do this:

```
DatabaseMetaData md = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = dbmd.getColumns(null, null, tableName, "%"); 
while(rs.next()) { 
    String column = rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME"); 
    System.out.println(column); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get table level metadata from various methods on [DatabaseMetaData](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html)

```
Connection c = ...;
DatabaseMetaData dmd = c.getMetaData();
ResultSet set = c.getColumns(catalogue, schema, table, columnPattern);
```

MySQL also supports INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables which you can also query for metadata. See
[MySQL 5.1 - INFORMATION_SCHEMA Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/tables-table.html)